# Invisible methods: a public method is unknown, private or protected

Tags: oop, debugging, abap

I have made a class with 2 static methods (really basic stuff) to use in a program.  The program that used it was not finished, and has not touched for a while (2 months maybe). I edited a method during that time and one day when I came back to working with the program that I originally made it for I got a compiler error saying "Method [method name] is unknown, PROTECTED or PRIVATE."

For the record, the same thing happens to all methods in this class regardless how they are defined (always public, although I tried changing it, I have tried both static and instance method types).

I have established there is nothing wrong with the class itself, because if I copy it to a temporary class (and use exact same call) I do not get compiler errors, but if I copy the temporary class back over original and use it again they come back. Unfortunately, it means this issue is impossible to reproduce until I learn what causes it.

As a final resort I can always use a different name, but that would mean violating naming convention, which I prefer to avoid if possible.

I am wondering if anybody know what might be causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, that was a buffer issue (it wasn't getting updated, or so we suspect).

Someone suggested T-code `/$sync` (which resets buffers), which fixed it.